# Minimum number of observations for longitudinal models?

Tags: regression

In longitudinal models, we calculate correlation/covariance of individual subjects (e.g. mice in lab)... but in many experiments, we only have 3-5 measurements for each subject. Generally, we say that 3 measurements is too few to calculate variance ... so does this mean that even though I have 1000 subjects, but if I only have 3-5 measurements per subject ... is longitudinal regression model not a good choice here? Realistically, do I need a minimum number of measurements per subject?

Comment: 1000 subjects with 3-5 measurements per subject seems like a very good sample size for many types of analyses. A multilevel regression or a latent growth curve model would probably work quite well in this type of data, of course depending on other data characteristics. What do you mean by  "longitudinal regression" exactly?